# Unable to instantiate SOAP Client - Failing with NullPointerException

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, javax.xml

While instantiating a SOAP client, I get NullPointerException

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "QWEServiceManager", targetNamespace = "http://external.ws.services.abc.com/", wsdlLocation = "file:/C:/Users/XYZ/Desktop/77777/QWEServiceManagerService.wsdl")
public class QWEServiceManagerService extends Service
```

When I try to create an instance of the client to call the SOAP service

```
QWEServiceManagerService serv = new QWEServiceManagerService()
```

the above throws

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to createEndpointReference Provider
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:160)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:92)
    at QWEServiceManagerService.<init>(QWEServiceManagerService .java:48)
    at WsClient.main(WsClient.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:152)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the fact that Java stopped providing default Provider Implementation above Java 6+.

It tries to find the Impl via following steps:

- First By Service Loader
- From JDK Properties (from $java.home/lib/jaxws.properties)
- Use the system property
- Lookup Using OSGi Service Loader

So, in simple, adding a dependency with implementation of provider solves the issue.

For me, adding [jaxws-rt](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2) dependency solved the issue.

Note: I faced another dependency issue for which I did need to add another dependency to 
[stax-ex](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet.staxex/stax-ex/1.8.1) to resolve all my dependency issues.